# Manage keydown in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, 2d-games

I am developing a program that will show a letter from an array. If the user press the up arrow this will move in the array, also if the user press the down arrow. 
The problem is that when I press any of these keys the letter moves very fast, for example if I am in the A the program moves till D or something like that.
Here is my code

```
def HighScore(event):
    pygame.init()
    nameString=""
    nameStringFinal=""
    index=0
    ABC=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    font=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",30,True,False)
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
    pygame.display.set_caption("New High Score" )
    font=pygame.image.load("imagenes/paisaje.jpg").convert()
    escape=False        
    while escape==False:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.blit(fondo,(0,0))
        show=fuente.render(nombreString,0,(0,0,0))

        if event.type ==  pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if control==True:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:  
                    if index==25:
                        index=25
                    else:
                        index=index+1
                    nameString=ABC[index]
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    if index==0:
                        index=0
                    else:
                        index=index-1
                    nameString=ABC[index]
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    nameStringFinal=nameStringFinal+nameString
        screen.blit(despliegue,(200,200))
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure all the event processing is indented properly, so it's part of the `for` loop

The way you have it now, the last even will be processed over and over until a new event arrives

For example:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    if event.type ==  pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:  
            if index==25:
                index=25
            else:
                index=index+1

            nameString=ABC[index]
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            if index==0:
                index=0
            else:
                index=index-1
            nameString=ABC[index]
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
            nameStringFinal=nameStringFinal+nameString

screen.blit(fondo,(0,0))
show=fuente.render(nombreString,0,(0,0,0))
screen.blit(despliegue,(200,200))
```

In the shell, you can see how a for loop over the empty list, just leaves the variable with the value of the previous loop

```
>>> for i in [1,2,3]:   # imagine this is the event list
...     if i == 4:
...         sys,exit()
... 
>>> if i == 3:
...     print "i==3"
... 
i==3
>>> for i in []:        # next time round the while loop, the event list is empty
...     if i == 4:
...         sys,exit()
... 
>>> if i == 3:          # but you're still processing this event again!
...     print "i==3"
... 
i==3
```